# Which word to use to introduce reason or justification of a requirement or recomendation

Tags: single-word-requests

When writing technical documents and different "guides", sometimes you need to explain or simply mention a reason or justification of a particular requirement or recommendation. Which word would you use as a "label" for such explanations? An example:

> Maximum number of characters per line: 72 or 78.
>
> **Reason:** This is exactly a line of 6 or 6.5 inches if using a 12-pitch font.

The word "reason" is used as an example, I'm not sure it really works here, and I'm not sure it will work good in a broader set of cases. Maybe "reasoning" or something different? I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Have you tried looking at other, similar guides from your discipline to see what term(s) they use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rationale** is a formal equivalent of 'the thinking behind this':

> *rationale* [noun]:
>
> a set of reasons or a logical basis for a course of action or belief.
>
> - *He explained the rationale behind the change*.

[[Oxford Languages; via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rationale+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=UYyuZMKMCKGlkdUPh4WbkAI&ved=0ahUKEwiC-cOkhomAAxWhUqQEHYfCBiIQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=rationale+meaning&gs_lcp=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-QEQlwUQjAUQ3QQQRhD0AxD1AxD2AxgCSgQIQRgAUABYoSNg3SZoAHABeACAAWGIAekJkgECMTeYAQCgAQHAAQHaAQYIARABGBTaAQYIAhABGBM&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

A simple ***explanation*** is less formal.

Comment: This. Or "motivation".

Answer (score 1):

**basis**

> the justification for or reasoning behind something
>
> —OL&G

---

JFYI, a short phrase: *The reason being,* …